# Pug dynamic image src interpolation

Tags: pug, pugjs

I have stored a dynamic url link into a pug variable #{img}. Now I want to include that variable into my image element. Can anyone help me fill in the blank?

```
#{img} //some dynamic url
img(src=" ") //want to set src = #{img}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

do it like this

```
- var img = "img/test.jpg"
img(src=img)
```

and [read this](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation)

Comment: Just realized I was using the deprecated version. The new version looks something like img(src=img). https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html